# Create and add a <li> element to an ordered list using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a To Do list, and when the user enters a new task, and clicks the button, the javascript should create a li element containing a span that holds the user's entry, then add that li element to the ol in my HTML.
My HTML looks like this:

```
<body>
    <h1>To Do:</h1>
    <section>

        <input type="text" id="add_todo">
        <span id="add_task_error">&nbsp;</span>
        <input type="button" id="add_task" value="Add task">

        <div id="empty_message" class="open">
            <h3>You have no tasks left to accomplish!</h3>
        </div>

        <div id="tasklist">
            <ol class="list">

            </ol>
        </div>

    </section>
</body>
```

This is the function that is not working:

```
        var newSpan = $('<span>input</span>').addClass("task");
        //wrap it in a <li> element
        newSpan = (".task").wrap("<li></li>");
        $(".list").append(newSpan);
```

I also tried it this way:

```
         var new_task = $('<li>*</li>').addClass('task');
         new_task.appendTo('ol.list');
         new_task.setAttribute('id', 'new_task');
         $("#new_task").text(input);
```

Both ways did not work- when I clicked the Add Task button (which is not the problem- I tested it), nothing happened on the screen...

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: can you share a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the element, set all the attributes and when, you are done, add it to the `ol`.

```
var new_task = $('<li></li>').addClass('task');
new_task.text($("#add_todo").val()); //this is the value of the input
new_task.attr('id', 'new_task'); //use attr instead of setAttribute    
new_task.appendTo('ol.list');
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2be901ns/)**

Comment: Yay! It works! Your solution seems so simple- it's pretty much just changing the order of how I did it originally, but I was stuck on this for days...

Comment: @Meg not just this,  the use of  `attr` is important.

Comment: How is it different than setAttribute?

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#add_task').click(function(){
    var task = $('#add_todo').val();
    var html = '<li><span>'+task+'</span></li>';
    $('.list').append(html);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>To Do:</h1>
    <section>

        <input type="text" id="add_todo">
        <span id="add_task_error">&nbsp;</span>
        <input type="button" id="add_task" value="Add task">

        <div id="empty_message" class="open">
            <h3>You have no tasks left to accomplish!</h3>
        </div>

        <div id="tasklist">
            <ol class="list">

            </ol>
        </div>

    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be your code.
Call addLI()  on click of your button

```
<input type="button" id="add_task" value="Add task" onclick="addLI()">

function addLI() {
    //check for empty value
    if ($('#add_todo').val() == "") {
        alert("Please Add Todo.");
        return;
    }
    //generate html for li
    var html = "<li class='task' id='new_task'><span>" + $('#add_todo').val() + "</li>";

    //append li to order list
    $(".list").append(html);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you

JS code:

```
$("#add_task").click(function(){
    var value = $("#add_todo").val();
    $(".list").append("<li class='task'><span>"+ value +"</span></li>")
});
```

Here is the working [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SKJxjmSH1X0WLlwTTQE5?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Also try to hide the div on which you are showing the message before adding any new task.

```
<div id="empty_message" class="open">
            <h3>You have no tasks left to accomplish!</h3>
        </div>
```

`$('.open').hide();` on click event of add task